# OnEditorAction not being called inside a DialogFragment

Tags: android, listener, android-alertdialog

I wanted to add a neat functionality to my `Dialog`. When the user presses `DONE` button on the keyboard after editing one of `EditTexts` inside the dialog, it would simulate `onPositiveClick` of the dialog so that the data inside the `EditTexts` gets handled properly and the dialog is dismissed. This is much better than first entering the data and then pressing the dialogs OK button. My dialog extends `DialogFragment` and implements `OnEditorActionListener` and this is my listener method:

```
@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((actionId & EditorInfo.IME_MASK_ACTION) == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)//check if done was pressed
        dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).performClick();
    return false;
}
```

But the problem is that this method is never called when i press `DONE` on my keyboard. Do you know what causes that?

Comment: Did you set the `OnEditorActionListener` on your `EditText`?

Comment: Well that's embarassing. I didn't. Thank you and sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Lol! No problem, we all have been there